# Best practice to build an API service receive and response XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I'm developing an API using Java.

The requirement is receive request and response in XML format.

I don't have much experiences about this before.

So I want to ask a best practice to build this system.

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with Restful Frameworks:

1. Apache CXF
2. Jersey (popular)
3. Restlet (pioneer of JAX-RS)
4. RESTEasy

Following is the comparison of above frameworks:

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-vs-apache-axis-vs

Out of 4 above the most popular are:

1. Apache CXF
2. Jersey

Lets have a look at both on following link

[Java REST implementation: Jersey vs CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704700/java-rest-implementation-jersey-vs-cxf)

But on the other hand people also recommend to use SPRING MVC if we are already familiar with Spring as it has full support for REST.

Following are the two very helpful articles on SPRING MVC VS JERSEY

http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs

http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

Moreover, we can integrate Spring and JERSEY together as well

Some more information:

Jersey:

Pros: Standard API (JAX-RS)
Cons: MVC support is less richer than Spring MVC.
Spring:

Pros: Many features, many documents, active community.
Cons: Many rules to learn.

Comment: also, Play framework.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for your answer ^_^

Comment: I found some articles about Spring and Play ( http://vschart.com/compare/play-framework/vs/spring-framework , http://www.quora.com/Play-Framework-versus-Spring-MVC-how-to-decide-what-to-use ). So should I choose Play ?

Comment: I never used play so i cant say anything about it! I have used Spring alot and it is very powerful.

Comment: So the best way you suggest is SPRING MVC ?

Comment: Yes! for me SPRING MVC is the best if you are already familiar with SPRING.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll start with Spring MVC. Sorry but would you please give me any tutorial to build a Restful application using Spring MVC?

Comment: 1-https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/     2 -http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/