# How to choose between Jersey, Apache Wink and JBoss RESTEasy?

Tags: apache, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I just heard about [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/), and I was wondering what differences it had compared to [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [JBoss RESTEasy](http://jboss.org/resteasy).  What can be done in one that the other two can't?

We've been using Jersey for some of our internal projects mostly for it's simplicity, but I can't really figure out what makes these other two any better that I would consider switching.  Does anyone have any use-cases for which niche each of these fills?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/80799/1725096

Answer (score 114, accepted):

## JAX-RS Implementations

### Jersey

- Reference Implementation
- Usually the most cutting edge
- Supports true asynchronous (ie web sockets etc...) connections through either [Atmosphere](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/atmosphere-0-8-jersey-on-steroid-websocket-sub-protocol-native-websocket-jquery-plugin-cors-rest-over-http/) or 2.0 version.
- Has support for Spring and standard injection containers (ie @Inject).
- Glassfish bundles it.
- Its much more modular than the other JAX-RS projects.
- It has a kick ass [URI Builder](https://jersey.github.io/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html)
- Does not necessarily require servlet container.
- Grizzly support
- Netty support (very early).
- [Swagger support](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-jaxrs)
- Sort of missing OAuth 2.0 . You'll have to use other libraries.
- Some MVC support through [Viewables](https://jersey.github.io/nonav/apidocs/1.1.0-ea/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/view/Viewable.html)
- Hosted on java.net (a minus as the site is terribly slow at times).
- Licensing is based on CCDL 1.1 and GPL-v2. Please make sure you check Jersey licensing before you use it for commercial use

https://jersey.github.io/license.html

### RestEasy

- Much of the above but most notable supports view technologies (see [HTMLEasy](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/))
- It does have [asynchronous connection support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html)
- [Cache support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Cache_NoCache_CacheControl.html)
- [EJB support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_EJB_Integration.html) (if your into that crap)
- JBoss bundles it (I think)
- [Netty support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d0e2690)
- Arguably the best [Spring integration (MVC handler)](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-2/userguide/html_single/index.html#SpringMVC).
- [Early Swagger support](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/resteasy)
- More security support including [early OAuth 2.0 support](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-jaxrs)

### Apache Wink <strike>(never used it)</strike>

- I have no idea why this project exists.
- Supposedly its high performance focused.
- It has a client built on top of HttpUrlConnection (which is a minus... it should be pluggable like [Spring RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)).
- Basically Wink was developed in house at some enterprise companies and then given to Apache.
- Requires a servlet container.

### Restlet

- Very powerful but very complicated
- Provides some low-level REST support
- Does not require a servlet container

### Apache CXF

- Some interesting WADL support.
- Reuse and or combine JAX-RS w/ JAX-WS
- Security support
- Integration w/ Spring albeit kind of nasty
- Supposed Autogeneration of client stubs

## Other RPC-like systems

### Message Queues

- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- ActiveMQ

### Asynchronous RPC

- [Finagle](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/) -- from Twitter.
- [msgpack-rpc](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-rpc)

## My humble opinion

I know the OP asked for REST but if this is for internal communication seriously consider using either a message queue or some other asynchronous RPC (Finagle) instead of traditional REST if your requirements match those systems.

If it must be classic HTTP REST (external) I would choose between either **RestEasy** or **Jersey** as a bulk of the mind share is put into those two projects.

Also see: [Rest clients for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java)

Comment: I don't recommend Jersey (I only tried v 2.5.1) one bit. It's extremely hard to configure and setup in the first place.

Comment: Can you explain why Restlet is complicated from your point of view. Have a look at the first steps example: http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-server

Comment: Perhaps "complicated" is not the right word and restlet also has evolved. I guess when I looked at restlet it seems to be way more stuff than jaxrs. It probably is the most comprehensive rest server library hence the "complicated".

Comment: It does have a much broader REST/HTTP feature scope, 6 editions, 44 editions and been around since 2005, but its core org.restlet.jar is very compact (zero dependency), unified client and server. Have a look at our first steps example, to see how you can get started in 5 minutes without having to configure any Servlet container or XML config. But still, you can grow/scale very far: http://restlet.com/discover/firststeps

Answer (score 16):

When choosing the implementation to use have this in mind: if you try to deploy a Jersey web service to JBOSS 7.1, it will not work. This error will occur:

```
Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed
```

This is because REST Easy comes bundled with JBOSS as the default JAX-RS implementation. So, JBOSS will decide that that's the implementation you want to use and will not load another JAX-RS implementation (like Jersey). In order to fix this, you need to add the following lines to your web.xml file:

```
  <context-param>
   <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param> 
   <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
   <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Link: https://community.jboss.org/message/744530

Comment: This is very useful information (although it answers a different question).

Comment: My guess is (long time since I've worked with JBOSS stuff) is that you can exclude the provided JAX-RS in JBOSS. Or you can exclude it in your pom. Bottom line: this is a problem you can work around.

Answer (score 5):

One of my favourite [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) extensions is Viewables.  Viewables allow you to bind your data easily to a JSP page to implement a true Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture:

- http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj

Comment: You've made that comment more than once. I would say the opposite. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use JBoss 7.x you must use RestEasy, 'cause it's integrated in JBoss. To use Jersey with JBoss 7.x, you have to disable RestEasy and it is complicated!

Comment: See the answer by Tihomir Meščić.