# What is diffrence between RESTEasy and jersey

Tags: java, jsp, rest, jersey, resteasy

i am working with java restfull services, i want a light weight rest server with jetty.

1. What is actual difference between jersey and rest-eassy?
2. Which is light weight?
3. In which scenario i want to chose jersey or rest-eassy?

Comment: Two different flavours of JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: @JunedAhsan thanku i fond this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459795/how-to-choose-between-jersey-apache-wink-and-jboss-resteasy