# Restlet + mongoDB + Freemarker

Tags: mongodb, freemarker, restlet, kundera

We are making a web based application in Java that should be accessible to any device and so we zeroed in for Restlet for our REST based web service need. 
For UI we are thinking of Freemarker together with Twitter bootstrap and database will be mongoDB. And guice for dependency injection. 
Since I am new to most these technology stack, do you think this is fair choice for a long run. Also, for database mapper framework we decided to use Jongo it seems lightweight. Kundera is an option but it has lots of dependency. What you expert say ?

Answer (score 1):

"Kundera is an option but it has lots of dependency." Not sure what do you mean by this statement? could you please explain it more? 
Please take a look at https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Kundera-Mongo-performance for performance using Kundera!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your needs

**REST Framework :**

IHMO you should test at least theses 3 JAX-RS Frameworks : RestEasy / Jersey / Restlet and choose the one according to your needs.

[JAX-RS Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80799/jax-rs-frameworks)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey

**UI :**

I've worked with Jersey + Freemarker through a framework called [Webengine](http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/WebEngine+%28JAX-RS%29) from Nuxeo, it was ok.

Nevertheless, you should consider a rich client approach based on Javascript/CSS/HTML (see Backbone.js, Ember.js)

Pros :
With such approach you could expose JSON REST services using a JAX-RS Framework (instead of freemarker/html services) . 
Theses services can be consumed by a web application and/or native mobile apps (ios, android).

Cons:
Your team must have advanced javascript skills (this [blog](http://addyosmani.com/blog/) can help )

**Database :**

What kind of data do you need to store ?

MongoDB is document-oriented and flexible enough to cover lots of needs

As you said, [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) is a lightweight API (500 lines of code + 1 dependency) over mongo-java-driver.

It allows you to query MongoDB as if you were in MongoShell (ie. with plain json/bson queries) and map your object using jackson. 
This question is a good example: [Mongo DB query in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444038/mongo-db-query-in-java/10445169)

Answer (score 0):

Relying on Restlet Framework for your RESTful web API/service backend sounds like a good choice for a multi-devices application. FreeMarker is very powerful and flexible so you should be in good company there as well.

I don't know too much about the other pieces of your stack.

Comment: Thanks for the post, this answer made me comfortable.