# Mongo DB query in java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

I have to write a complex mongo query using java but am not able to do it.

The mongo query looks like this:

```
db.video.findOne( { 
    $or: [ 
        { key1: { $in : [764] } }, 
        { key2: {$in : [list2] } }, 
        { $and [ { key2 : 3}, {key4:67} ] } 
    ]
})
```

I have to write the above query using the QueryBuilder class.  In what way can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using QueryBuilder your query should look like this

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().or(
    QueryBuilder.start("key1").in(764).get(),
    QueryBuilder.start("key2").in(keys).get(),
    QueryBuilder.start().and("key3").is(3).and("key4").is(64).get()
 ).get();
```

Consider using [jongo](http://jongo.org) (an API over mongo-java-driver) you can simply copy/paste queries from the shell :

```
collection.findOne("{$or:[{key1: {$in:[764]}},{key2:{$in:[#]}}, {$and:[{key3:3},{key4:67}]}]}", keys).as(People.class);
```

Comment: But how to execute query(DBObject) ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and i got a solution in another way :

```
ArrayList orList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList andList = new ArrayList();

orList.add(new BasicDBObject("key1", new BasicDBObject("$in", 764)));                  
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("key2", new BasicDBObject("$in", list2)));

andList.add(new BasicDBObject("key2", 3));
andList.add(new BasicDBObject("key4", 67));

orList.add(new BasicDBObject("$and", andList));

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", orList);
```

Comment: But how to execute query(DBObject) ?